# Docker Golang onbuild custom action at docker run

Tags: go, docker, dockerfile

I have a fairly easy Dockerfile for a Go app:

```
FROM golang:onbuild
EXPOSE 5000 5001
```

Now when I run it (not when building the image!) I would like to change a value in a html file which gets statically served, possibly using `sed` to use an environment variable previously specified with `-e` to docker run. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
FROM golang:onbuild
COPY ./docker-entrypoint.sh /

EXPOSE 5000 5001
ENTRYPOINT ["/docker-entrypoint.sh"]
```

**Note**: you need to copy entry point file with your sed script somewhere into container (done on line 2)

and *docker-entrypoint.sh* with your `sed` script

```
# execute sed only **if variable exists**
sed -ri "s/<title>.*/<title>$ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE</title>/" /path_to_html_file/index.html
```

- simple example of replacement line with new title (passed in run as env. variable) in index.html file

**Note**: just keep in mind to run sed only if environment variable was served as @STLMikey shows.

and run docker container with `$ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE`

eg:

```
docker run -d -t -i -e ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE='New website title' --name=container_name IMAGE_NAME
```

Answer (score 1):

One option is to use the `--entrypoint` option during docker run:

```
docker run --entrypoint /some/sh/script.sh <imagename>
```

where script.sh is a file *inside* your container, and contains something like:

```
#!/bin/env bash    
if [[ "$myenvvar" == 'myvalue' ]]; then
    # sed your file here
else
    #don't do that
fi
```

If you dont like the idea of overriding the entrypoint at run time, you might consider using the `CMD` or `ENTRYPOINT` options in your Dockerfile.